# WPF Datagrid Combox editable

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, combobox

My goal it's to put a `ComboBox` editable in a `DataGrid`, for that I put a `TextBlock` in `CellTemplate` and a `ComboBox` in `CellEditingTemplate`. But how bind my `TextBlock` with the text of selected item in `ComboBox` ?

```
        var textBlockFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
        textBlockFactory.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("Description"));
        dgc.ClipboardContentBinding = new Binding("Description");

        var template = new DataTemplate();
        template.VisualTree = textBlockFactory;
        dgc.CellTemplate = template;


        var comboBoxFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ComboBox));
        template = new DataTemplate();
        template.VisualTree = comboBoxFactory;

        Binding b = new Binding();
        b.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(UserControl), 1);
        b.Path = new PropertyPath(BindingList);
        comboBoxFactory.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, b);
        comboBoxFactory.SetValue(ComboBox.IsEditableProperty, true);
        comboBoxFactory.SetValue(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty, new Binding("Type"));
        comboBoxFactory.SetValue(ComboBox.SelectedValuePathProperty, "Id");
        comboBoxFactory.SetValue(ComboBox.DisplayMemberPathProperty, "Description");

        dgc.CellEditingTemplate = template;
        dgc.SortMemberPath = BindingCurrentItem;
```

Comment: ["This class is a deprecated way to programmatically create templates, which are subclasses of FrameworkTemplate such as ControlTemplate or DataTemplate; not all of the template functionality is available when you create a template using this class. The recommended way to programmatically create a template is to load XAML from a string or a memory stream using the Load method of the XamlReader class."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory.aspx) Seriously?

Comment: Why do you need to do this in code?

Comment: If you had done this the "proper" xaml way - a simple ElementName binding would have done all that in under 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular scenario, you will have to make one more property say SelectedBinding in your model backing your DataGridItem. The type of property should be of type of item in your BindingList.

Then you can bind the SelectedItem of your ComboBox to it as

```
comboBoxFactory.SetValue(ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty, new Binding("SelectedBinding"));
```

and you can update your TextBlock binding as

```
  dgc.ClipboardContentBinding = new Binding("SelectedBinding.Description");
```